# Jquery load a fragment of external file (n divs)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to load contents of an external file into master html piece by piece. I managed to load the first part, but I don't know how to select the next one. Ideally, the next part is loaded on scroll (when one hits the bottom of the page) - scroll function works for me too, so the only problem is how to select the next fragment of external html.

My master template:

```
<div id='master'> 
  // This is where to load external divs
</div>
```

External file has all the divs I want to load:

```
<div cls='new'> </div>
<div cls='new'> </div>
<div cls='new'> </div>
...
```

I started with loading the first 10 elements into my empty master template (this works) and then try to load the next 10 elements in loop using gt selector (this is my last idea for this problem, but not working):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  x = 10;
  $('#master').load('external.html .new:lt('+x+')',function() {

    var size_master = $("#master .new").length;
    master = document.getElementById('master');

    y = size_master + 1; // current number of divs on master template +1
    z = y+10; // append y by the next 10 divs from external.html

    master.onscroll = function() {
      if(master.scrollTop + master.clientHeight == master.scrollHeight) {
      for (var i = y; i < z; i++) {  
        $('#master').last().load('external.html .new:gt('+i+')');
      };
      };
    };
  });
});
```

I don't want to load the whole external file at the beginning as it is huge and loading it gradually is supposed to make the web work smoothly.

I was also thinking of using slice(start,end) function on external.html to select the next part of divs to load but I can't make it work.

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get an error? Also, can you create a snippet where we could easily reproduce the problem? (you could use an HTML container instead of the external file if it is simpler that way to create a reproducible example).

Comment: Sorry for not specifying that. At first I get my initial 10 divs loaded, but when I include onscroll function to load the next 10 my master template is empty again (and I get no errors). When it comes to the slice function, I don't know how to use it inside load() or append(). I'll try to make a snippet to better explain the problem.

Comment: Mira, the first problem that I can see is that you have the `master.onscroll` definition inside the `load` function's function parameter. You should define it outside the `load`. The second problem that your `if` seems to be incorrect: `if(master.scrollTop + master.clientHeight == master.scrollHeight) {`. If you could create a snippet or a fiddle, then I could test and make sure that this is fixed.